# Using libclang as a compiler

Tags: llvm, clang

I'm working on a tool that generates C code from a specification. Users thus need to compile themselves the generated code before using the compiled code with another tool. I would like to automate this tedious process. Rather than calling a process, I wonder if it is possible, using libclang, to directly embed the compiler?

Comment: check out this blog [post](https://wiki.nervtech.org/doku.php?id=blog:2020:0410_dynamic_cpp_compilation), also you can use `cc1_main` [here](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/main/clang/tools/driver/cc1_main.cpp#L184) and pass in the args to achieve that. Both approach don't use libclang tho

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue? If yes, could you share your solution, please?

Comment: @0dminnimda If I recall correctly, we sticked with calling gcc/clang in a subprocess.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, it is possible *for some version of clang/llvm*. You can start from http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project/cfe/trunk/tools/driver/cc1_main.cpp?revision=126577&view=markup = this is a source of `clang` binary itself. It does invoke a <s>libclang</s> library and you can integrate this code into you application. *(Actually, it uses unstable C++ interfaces from internal clang and llvm libraries, not the stable C API of libclang.)*

If you save all C sources in the file, this is all you need. But if you want to pass sources directly via memory, you should write custom `SourceManager` and set with `setSourceManager()` method of   `CompilerInvocation Clang`.

Comment: I'm not sure that clang is fully started from cc1_main.cpp file (linked to), so also check the driver.cpp file in the same directory.

Comment: @osgx What functions need to be called specifically? I am trying to do this and almost none of the lines work due to missing this and that. What is the bare minimum that one would need to specify a .c file and get machine code spit out?

Comment: @SevenBits, use current version of this file.  You also can ask new question

Comment: Note that this actually isn't `libclang`, `libclang` is a C interface, this is the C++ interface which isn't stable.

Comment: kralyk, thank you for comment. Can you add your own answer to the question (how to use libclang to embed the clang+llvm as c/c++ compiler)? libclang was created (http://llvm.org/devmtg/2010-11/Gregor-libclang.pdf) as interface for parsing/indexing/xrefing/highlighting/completion in 2010. Was it expanded to compiler-embedding library?